# C# preprocessor directive ignored in Visusal Studio 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor, visual-studio-express

I have a section of code downloaded from [codeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SampleGrabber.aspx?fid=1538273&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=51#xx0xx).

The `#if` preprocessor directive doesn't appear to work like I would have expected it to work.

I have not defined DSHOWNET in MyProject >> Properties >> Build Tab >> Conditional compilation symbols (the dialog box is empty)

In the code below, an error *DShowNET could not be found* is shown when the project is built.  Since DSHOWNET was never defined, I'm surprised that the 'using DShowNET' is even processed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#if DSHOWNET
using DShowNET;
using DShowNET.Device;
#else
#if VS2003
#else
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
#endif
using DirectShowLib;
#endif
```

Does the #if preprocessor directive work in the Visual Studio Express version?  Does DSHOWNET need to be explicitly 'undefined'?  Or am I missing some other basic concept?

Comment: Look at the code inside the `#if DSHOWNET
` statement - is it greyed out, or does it have its normal syntax coloring?

Comment: @slugster, The syntax coloring showed that the statements after the else were ignored.  shelleybutterfly downloaded the code and found that DSHOWNET WAS defined in another project within the solution.  Thanks for the hint on the syntax coloring, this will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded the sample grabber project and put it on my system. (I am using the Enterprise VS.)  I opened the `CaptureTest-2005` solution, converted it to a VS2010 solution, and loaded it.  Upon loading the `CaptureTest-2005` solution, I still saw files that had the same issue as you are seeing.

So, what I found was that, although the `CaptureTest-2005` project did not have `DSHOWNET` defined on the Build page, the `DirectX.Capture-2005` project did.  So, for all the files in `DirectX.Capture-2005`, the `DSHOWNET` directive evaluated to true, and thus the items inside the `#if DSHOWNET` directives were being processed.

I am not sure whether the solution just requires that you build and use the `DSHOWNET` part of the CodeProject download, (e.g. I'm not sure whether `DirectX.Capture` is required) but I imagine, since the `DirectX.Capture` project has it defined, that you will have to build and use that assembly to run the project. (There may be a way around it, I have not gone that far into it. I would recommend checking the project page to see if there's information about what depends on what.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for digging into this so thoroughly!

Comment: Microsoft does some 'interesting' things in the express version of VisualStudion.  In the IDE, Project Properties, Build tab the conditional compilation symbols is blank.  However if you open up the .csproj file with notepad++ there is an xml line <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;VS2003;DSHOWNET</DefineConstants> that defines the constants!

Comment: that is 'interesting' :) you might file a bug report at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio ; I can't find a bug report related to this, so it might be something peculiar about this particular .csproj.